# Good way to access MacBook local server on ipad?

Tags: ipad

I'm working on developing web apps for ipad and I was wondering if there's a good & relatively simple way to host on my local server during development and access that on my ipad to see the site without needing to host online.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in luck!  OSX comes with Apache :)

http://www.klauskomenda.com/archives/2008/10/07/installing-apache-mysql-and-php-on-leopard/ is a good place to start.

Comment: cool, got me started any way.  I ended up just using MAMP and it worked great.